# MongoDB - match id of a collection with the given array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a student collection like below,

```
{_id:22222, student_id:1}
{_id:22223, student_id:2}
{_id:22224, student_id:3}
{_id:22225, student_id:4}
```

I have an array like [1,2], and I want to return only the documents that as the same student_id in the array.

if the array is [1,3], the output should be also in an array
[1,3]

if I have array like [4,7], and since 7 is not a valid student_id, it should return only
[4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use with aggregate with match keyword

```
db.Signal.aggregate(
  {$match:{student_id:{$in:[4,3]}}},
  {$project:{_id:0,'student_id':1}},
  { $group: { _id: null, student: { $push:'$student_id' } } }
)
```

Comment: we need output as an array

Comment: @user3470294 please check this query now, I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use the [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator:

```
db.students.find({
   student_id: { $in: [1, 7] }
})
```

Comment: thanks. it worked. is there an aggreate framework also, we will to have projections and a match before.

Comment: also the output should be in an array